# AWS Lambda access denied to a module in subfolder

Tags: node.js, gulp, aws-lambda

I have this Nodejs lambda function where some files are in a subfolder, like this:

```
- index.js
- connectors/
    - affil.js
```

I have a `Cannot find module` error when trying to require the `affil.js` file. Trying to read it with `fs.readFile` returns an `access denied` error.

When I move the file to the root folder, it is accessible. Is there a requirement that Lambda functions files must all be at the root directory? How can I fix that?

Comment: how did you deploy the lambda? Deployed it as zip?

Comment: yes, zip file created with `gulp-zip`.

Comment: Mostly the problem with zip. I have added an answer which I have solved the issue. Please give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it is because of the way zipping the files making the problem. Instead of zipping the root folder you have to select all files and zip it like below,

Please upload all files and subfolders like below. Please include node_modules folder as well in the zip.

[image]

Comment: A manually created zip actually solves the issue. But that's not what I'd call automatic deployment :). Will investigate `gulp-zip`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Vijayanath Viswanathan, the issue is with how the zip file is created rather than Lambda.

I used to feed `gulp-zip` with this:

```
var src = gulp.src('src/**/*')
```

The correct way is to prevent folders from being included:

```
var src = gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
```

or (if you need to include file with other file extensions)

```
var src = gulp.src('src/**/*', {nodir: true})
```